# MYSQL: Difference between Binary and Blob

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to understand mysql data types, but i don't get the difference between the (Var-)BINARY data fields and the BLOB-Fields. What ist the difference between these types?

Answer (score 19):

BLOB's can be as big as you want.

Also, reading the MySQL manual online:

> BLOB and TEXT differ from VARBINARY and VARCHAR in the following ways:
>
> - There is no trailing-space removal for BLOB and TEXT columns when
>     values are stored or retrieved. Before MySQL 5.0.3, this differs from
>     VARBINARY and VARCHAR, for which trailing spaces are removed when
>     values are stored.
> - On comparisons, TEXT is space extended to fit the compared object,
>     exactly like CHAR and VARCHAR.
> - For indexes on BLOB and TEXT columns, you must specify an index prefix
>     length. For CHAR and VARCHAR, a prefix length is optional. See Section
>     7.5.1, “Column Indexes”.
> - BLOB and TEXT columns cannot have DEFAULT values.

Comment: 'As big as you want' as long as it's less than 2^32B (for LONGBLOB).
Also: *TEXT and *BLOB columns are not stored alongside all other columns, so accessing them might be a bit slower, but on the plus side, they do not count towards 64kB max row size.

Answer (score 9):

The binary and varbinary types are binary strings whose actual values are stored in the table. The actual values blob (and text) types are stored elsewhere in the database with a 256 byte alias to that slot being placed in the table; the blob can therefore be "any" size (up to the max).