# FIle Upload to MySQL Blob dataype some image not rendered properly

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, file-upload

Im uploading an image file using javascript FileReader, my code is below to get the binary data like this:

```
var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $(".image-preview-input-title").text("Change");
        $(".image-preview-clear").show();            
        img.attr('src', e.target.result);
        $(".image-preview-filename").val(file.name);  
        $(".image-preview").attr("data-content",$(img)[0].outerHTML).popover("show");
        $("#create_image").val(e.target.result);
        $("#edit_image").val(e.target.result);
        $("#create_image_name").val(file.name);
        $("#edit_image_name").val(file.name);
    }        
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

and my ajax code i use serialize for the form

```
 var dataSerialize = $("#create-interred-form").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "./db.php?action=createInterred",
                    data: dataSerialize,
                    success: function (data){
                        if (data == "200") {
                            swal({
                                title: "New Interred successfully created!",
                                text: "",
                                type: "success",
                                allowOutsideClick: false,
                                allowEscapeKey: false
                            },
                            function(){
                                location.reload();
                            });
                        } else {
                            swal("Error!","An unexpected error occur. Please try again later.", "error");
                        }
                    }                       
                });
```

in my php code i use a simple query to save and retrieve:

Save:

```
function createInterred(){
    include ('config.php');
    $user_id = $_POST['userList'];
    $interred_name = $_POST['interred_name'];
    $date_birth = $_POST['date_birth'];
    $date_death = $_POST['date_death'];
    $date_interred = $_POST['date_interred'];
    $date_purchased = $_POST['date_purchased'];
    $class_id = $_POST['class'];
    $block = $_POST['block'];
    $lot = $_POST['lot'];
    $phase = $_POST['phase'];
    $latitude = $_POST['create_latitude'];
    $longitude = $_POST['create_longitude'];
    $created_by = $_POST['created_by'];
    $date_created = $_POST['date_created'];
    $image = $_POST['create_image'];
    $image_name = $_POST['create_image_name'];

    try {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO interred(user_id, interred_name, date_interred, date_purchased, class_id, block, lot, phase, latitude, longitude, created_by, date_created, date_birth, date_death, image, image_name) VALUES(:user_id, :interred_name, :date_interred, :date_purchased, :class_id, :block, :lot, :phase, :latitude, :longitude, :created_by, :date_created, :date_birth, :date_death, :image, :image_name)");
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':user_id' => $user_id,
            ':interred_name' => $interred_name,
            ':date_interred' => $date_interred,
            ':date_purchased' => $date_purchased,
            ':class_id' => $class_id,
            ':block' => $block,
            ':lot' => $lot,
            ':phase' => $phase,
            ':latitude' => $latitude,
            ':longitude' => $longitude,
            ':created_by' => $created_by,
            ':date_created' => $date_created,
            ':date_birth' => $date_birth,
            ':date_death' => $date_death,
            ':image' => $image,
            ':image_name' => $image_name
        ));
    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo "500";
    }

    echo "200";

    $dbh = null;
}
```

Retrieve:

```
function getAllInterred(){
    include ('config.php');

    try{
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM  interred AS i, user AS u, user_info AS ui WHERE i.user_id = u.user_id AND u.user_info_id = ui.user_info_id ORDER BY interred_name"); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($count > 0){
            $json = json_encode($result);
            echo $json;
        } else {
            echo "300";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo "500";
    }

    $dbh = null;
}
```

Now i use to save this on a variable list the result of my retrieve and iterate each value to show in `ul li`. when a user click on `li` item i use filter to get the value of the selected item

```
 var result = $.grep(allInterredList, function(e){ return e.interred_id == interredSelected; });

        if (result.length > 0) {
            $("#oInterredName").html(result[0].interred_name);
            $("#oDateBirth").html(moment(result[0].date_birth).format('MMMM DD, YYYY'));
            $("#oDateDeath").html(moment(result[0].date_death).format('MMMM DD, YYYY'));
            $("#oDateInterred").html(moment(result[0].date_interred).format('MMMM DD, YYYY'));
            $("#oLotOwner").html(result[0].fname + " " + result[0].lname);
            $("#oAddress").html(result[0].address);
            $("#oPhone").html(result[0].contact_no); 
            $("#oDatePurchased").html(moment(result[0].date_purchased).format('MMMM DD, YYYY')); 
            $("#oBlock").html(result[0].block); 
            $("#oLot").html(result[0].lot); 
            $("#oPhase").html(result[0].phase);
            if (result[0].class_id == 1){
                $("#oClass").html("LA - Lot Area");  
            } else if (result[0].class_id == 2){
                $("#oClass").html("BC- Bone Chamber");  
            } else if (result[0].class_id == 3){
                $("#oClass").html("FE - Family Estate");  
            } else {
                $("#oClass").html("GA - Garden Area");  
            }
            $("#oCreatedBy").html(result[0].created_by);
            $("#oDateCreated").html(moment(result[0].date_created).format('MMMM DD, YYYY'));
            $("#oModifiedBy").html(result[0].modified_by);
            $("#oModifiedDate").html((result[0].date_modified == undefined) ? '' : moment(result[0].date_modified).format('MMMM DD, YYYY'));
            $("#oImage").attr('src', (result[0].image != null && result[0].image != "") ? result[0].image : "img/no_image_found.gif");
            $("#btnViewMap").prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            swal({
                title: "Unexpected Error Occured!",
                text: "Cannot find the selected user data. Logging out.",
                type: "error",
                allowOutsideClick: false,
                allowEscapeKey: false
            },
            function(){
                sessionStorage.clear();
                window.location.href = "index.html";
            });
        }
```

Now, my problem is some images are shown correctly. example below

[image]

while of it has error showing this

[image]

this is the error line:

[image]

Note: the above image has bigger file size compared to the bottom one

Comment: @JaromandaX what do you mean GET? i use get method i did not post it since its long. as you can see i can retrieve the data and show it

Comment: i dont use GET method onclick on the list, and also i only use the GET method only once. the error shows only onclick but some of the images not showing that error. please re read. you are misleading

Comment: Nevermind - I'll remove my "noise" seeing as you're sure that error isn't important

Comment: Can you post the ajax get method, particularly the response portion? I believe you have to deserialize the data just as you serialized it on the POST. Furthermore, I believe you need to use a binary and not a blob. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421933/mysql-difference-between-binary-and-blob