# Is there any syntax error in this MySQL code?

Tags: mysql-error-1064

I would like to create a column in a table, with data type BLOB and attribute BINARY, however, MySQL always says that there is a syntax error in my code, I cannot see any.

My code is:

```
ALTER TABLE `Users` CHANGE `user_image` `user_image` BLOB BINARY NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

And the error message is:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BINARY NULL DEFAULT NULL' at line 1.

Answer (score 0):

Modify existing column

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype;
```

Add a new column

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype;
```

Comment: It doesn't work...I got the same error again. It seems that the BINARY attribute caused the problem, because every time the error message says "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BINARY NULL DEFAULT NULL' at line 1."

Comment: datatype should be either blob or binary, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421933/mysql-difference-between-binary-and-blob